# Let's make this Order nicer

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

#### Environment details

- Python 3.6.5
- Django 2.0 (which is not necessarily needed for this review)

---

#### Class details

I have a small class which holds 3 `staticmethod`s (I know they should be avoided and use simple functions instead, but I decided to have them all together under the same class).

Each of these methods generates a description based on some information (`validated_data` and `vm_x, .., db_x, ..,`). The last method decides what description get's returned based on a dropdown.

---

#### Code

```
class OrderDescription:
    
    @staticmethod
    def standalone(validated_data):
        vm_1, db_1 = UsdDBActions().reserve_ci(2)

        payload = [
            {
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
                'hostname': vm_1,
                'number_of_cpu': validated_data['cpu_licenses'],
                'ram_gb': validated_data['compute_units'] * 7,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Computing & Internal Outsourcing',
                'twenty_four_team': '24H STAID Computing and Internal Outsourcing',
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'ci': vm_1,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Virtual Server',
            },
            {
                'hostname': validated_data['database_name'],
                'attached_to_server': vm_1,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Database Oracle',
                'roleflagmanagement': 1,
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'model': 'Oracle 12.1.0.1',
                'ci': db_1,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Database',
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
            }
        ]

        created_vm_1 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(vm_1, payload[0])
        created_db_1 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(db_1, payload[1])

        if created_vm_1 and created_db_1:
            description = f"""
            Created VM: {vm_1}
            Created DB: {db_1}
            
            - Portal information
            - Create network assets and log IP information in CMDB.
                -> 1x IP address in VLAN {validated_data['environment'].vlan}
            - Create 1 x OVM type {validated_data['level']}
                -> VLAN: {validated_data['environment'].vlan}
                -> Primary Location: {validated_data['primary_location']}
                -> vCPU = {validated_data['cpu_licenses']}
                -> vMEm = {validated_data['compute_units'] * 7}
                -> vStorage = {validated_data['storage_capacity']}
            - Create 1 x Database type {validated_data['level']}
                -> Name: {validated_data['database_name']}
                -> Character set: {validated_data['character_set']}
                -> National Character set: {validated_data['national_character_set']}
                -> Type: {validated_data['level']}
                -> License: {validated_data['licence']}
                -> DNS information: {validated_data['dns'].server} - {validated_data['dns'].domain}
            - CSC request to enable monitoring
            - CSC to enable backup with retention {validated_data['backup'].retention}
            - Feedback
                -> Database Name (SID)
                -> Database port
                -> IP addresses
                -> Host name
                -> User/password
        """
        else:
            description = 'Could not create ci'

        response = {
            'description': textwrap.dedent(description),
            'created_vms': [vm_1],
            'created_dbs': [db_1],
            'created_clusters': [],
        }

        return response

    @staticmethod
    def cluster_dr(validated_data):
        vm_1, vm_2, db_1, db_2 = UsdDBActions().reserve_ci(4)

        payload = [
            {
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
                'hostname': vm_1,
                'number_of_cpu': validated_data['cpu_licenses'],
                'ram_gb': validated_data['compute_units'] * 7,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Computing & Internal Outsourcing',
                'twenty_four_team': '24H STAID Computing and Internal Outsourcing',
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'ci': vm_1,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Virtual Server',
            },
            {
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
                'hostname': vm_2,
                'number_of_cpu': validated_data['cpu_licenses'],
                'ram_gb': validated_data['compute_units'] * 7,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Computing & Internal Outsourcing',
                'twenty_four_team': '24H STAID Computing and Internal Outsourcing',
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'ci': vm_2,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Virtual Server',
            },
            {
                'hostname': validated_data['database_name'],
                'attached_to_server': vm_1,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Database Oracle',
                'roleflagmanagement': 1,
                'service_window': '247',
                'model': 'Oracle 12.1.0.1',
                'ci': db_1,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Database',
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
            },
            {
                'hostname': validated_data['database_name'],
                'attached_to_server': vm_2,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Database Oracle',
                'roleflagmanagement': 1,
                'service_window': '247',
                'model': 'Oracle 12.1.0.1',
                'ci': db_2,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Database',
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
            }
        ]

        created_vm_1 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(vm_1, payload[0])
        created_vm_2 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(vm_2, payload[1])
        created_db_1 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(db_1, payload[2])
        created_db_2 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(db_2, payload[3])

        if created_vm_1 and created_vm_2 and created_db_1 and created_db_2:
            description = f"""
            Created VMs: {vm_1, vm_2}
            Created DBs: {db_1, db_2}
            
            - Portal information
            - Create network assets and log IP information in CMDB.
                -> 2 x IP address in VLAN {validated_data['environment'].vlan}
            - Create Virtual server 1
                -> VLAN: {validated_data['environment'].vlan}
                -> Primary Location: {validated_data['primary_location']}
                -> vCPU = {validated_data['cpu_licenses']}
                -> vMEm = {validated_data['compute_units'] * 7}
                -> vStorage = {validated_data['storage_capacity']}
            - Create Virtual server 2
                -> VLAN: {validated_data['environment'].vlan}
                -> Primary Location: {validated_data['secondary_location']}
                -> vCPU = {validated_data['cpu_licenses']}
                -> vMEm = {validated_data['compute_units'] * 7}
                -> vStorage = {validated_data['storage_capacity']}
            - Create 1 x Database type {validated_data['level']}
                -> Name: {validated_data['database_name']}
                -> Character set: {validated_data['character_set']}
                -> National Character set: {validated_data['national_character_set']}
                -> Location: {validated_data['primary_location']}
                -> Type: {validated_data['level']}
                -> License: {validated_data['licence']}
                -> DNS information: {validated_data['dns'].server} - {validated_data['dns'].domain}
            - Create 1 x Database type {validated_data['level']}
                -> Name: {validated_data['database_name']}
                -> Character set: {validated_data['character_set']}
                -> National Character set: {validated_data['national_character_set']}
                -> Location: {validated_data['secondary_location']}
                -> Type: {validated_data['level']}
                -> License: {validated_data['licence']}
                -> DNS information: {validated_data['dns'].server} - {validated_data['dns'].domain}
            - CSC request to enable monitoring
            - CSC request to enable backup with retention {validated_data['backup'].retention}
            - Feedback
                -> Database Names (SID)
                -> Database ports
                -> IP addresses
                -> Host names
                -> 1 x User/password
        """
        else:
            description = 'Could not create ci'

        response = {
            'description': textwrap.dedent(description),
            'created_vms': [vm_1, vm_2],
            'created_dbs': [db_1, db_2],
            'created_clusters': [],
        }

        return response

    @staticmethod
    def geocluster_ha_dr(validated_data):
        cl_1, cl_2, vm_1, vm_2, vm_3, vm_4, db_1, db_2, db_3, db_4, db_5, db_6 = UsdDBActions().reserve_ci(12)

        payload = [
            {
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Cluster',
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'ci': cl_1,
                'hostname': f"{validated_data['database_name']} Active",
            },
            {
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Cluster',
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'ci': cl_2,
                'hostname': f"{validated_data['database_name']} Standby",
            },
            {
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
                'hostname': vm_1,
                'number_of_cpu': validated_data['cpu_licenses'],
                'ram_gb': validated_data['compute_units'] * 7,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Computing & Internal Outsourcing',
                'twenty_four_team': '24H STAID Computing and Internal Outsourcing',
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'ci': vm_1,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Virtual Server',
                'attached_to_server': cl_1
            },
            {
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
                'hostname': vm_2,
                'number_of_cpu': validated_data['cpu_licenses'],
                'ram_gb': validated_data['compute_units'] * 7,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Computing & Internal Outsourcing',
                'twenty_four_team': '24H STAID Computing and Internal Outsourcing',
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'ci': vm_2,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Virtual Server',
                'attached_to_server': cl_1,
            },
            {
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
                'hostname': vm_3,
                'number_of_cpu': validated_data['cpu_licenses'],
                'ram_gb': validated_data['compute_units'] * 7,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Computing & Internal Outsourcing',
                'twenty_four_team': '24H STAID Computing and Internal Outsourcing',
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'ci': vm_3,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Virtual Server',
                'attached_to_server': cl_2,
            },
            {
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
                'hostname': vm_4,
                'number_of_cpu': validated_data['cpu_licenses'],
                'ram_gb': validated_data['compute_units'] * 7,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Computing & Internal Outsourcing',
                'twenty_four_team': '24H STAID Computing and Internal Outsourcing',
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'ci': vm_4,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Virtual Server',
                'attached_to_server': cl_2,
            },
            {
                'hostname': f"{validated_data['database_name']}A1",
                'attached_to_server': vm_1,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Database Oracle',
                'roleflagmanagement': 1,
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'model': 'Oracle 12.1.0.1',
                'ci': db_1,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Database',
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
            },
            {
                'hostname': f"{validated_data['database_name']}A2",
                'attached_to_server': vm_3,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Database Oracle',
                'roleflagmanagement': 1,
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'model': 'Oracle 12.1.0.1',
                'ci': db_2,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Database',
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
            },
            {
                'hostname': f"{validated_data['database_name']}S1",
                'attached_to_server': vm_1,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Database Oracle',
                'roleflagmanagement': 1,
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'model': 'Oracle 12.1.0.1',
                'ci': db_3,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Database',
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
            },
            {
                'hostname': f"{validated_data['database_name']}S2",
                'attached_to_server': vm_1,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Database Oracle',
                'roleflagmanagement': 1,
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'model': 'Oracle 12.1.0.1',
                'ci': db_4,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Database',
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
            },
            {
                'hostname': f"{validated_data['database_name']}A",
                'attached_to_server': cl_1,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Database Oracle',
                'roleflagmanagement': 1,
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'model': 'Oracle 12.1.0.1',
                'ci': db_5,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Database',
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
            },
            {
                'hostname': f"{validated_data['database_name']}S",
                'attached_to_server': cl_2,
                'resolver_group': 'SSC.Database Oracle',
                'roleflagmanagement': 1,
                'service_window': 'businesshours',
                'model': 'Oracle 12.1.0.1',
                'ci': db_6,
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Database',
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
            }
        ]

        created_cl_1 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(cl_1, payload[0])
        created_cl_2 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(cl_2, payload[1])

        created_vm_1 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(vm_1, payload[2])
        created_vm_2 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(vm_2, payload[3])
        created_vm_3 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(vm_3, payload[4])
        created_vm_4 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(vm_4, payload[5])

        created_db_1 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(db_1, payload[6])
        created_db_2 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(db_2, payload[7])
        created_db_3 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(db_3, payload[8])
        created_db_4 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(db_4, payload[9])
        created_db_5 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(db_5, payload[10])
        created_db_6 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(db_6, payload[11])

        if (created_cl_1 and created_cl_2 and created_vm_1 and created_vm_2 and created_vm_3 and created_vm_4
                and created_db_1 and created_db_2 and created_db_3 and created_db_4 and created_db_5 and created_db_6):

            description = f"""
            Created VM: {vm_1, vm_2, vm_3, vm_4}
            Created DB: {db_1, db_2, db_3, db_4, db_5, db_6}
            Created Clusters: {cl_1, cl_2}
            
            - Portal information
            - Create network assets and log IP information in CMDB.
                -> 14 x IP address in VLAN {validated_data['environment'].vlan}
                -> IP range in VLAN {validated_data['environment'].vlan} (/29) 
                   + 4 IP addresses in range {validated_data['environment'].ip_range}
            - Create Virtual server 1
                -> VLAN: {validated_data['environment'].vlan}
                -> Primary Location: {validated_data['primary_location']}
                -> vCPU = {validated_data['cpu_licenses']}
                -> vMEm = {validated_data['compute_units'] * 7}
                -> vStorage = {validated_data['storage_capacity']}
            - Create Virtual server 2
                -> VLAN: {validated_data['environment'].vlan}
                -> Primary Location: {validated_data['primary_location']}
                -> vCPU = {validated_data['cpu_licenses']}
                -> vMEm = {validated_data['compute_units'] * 7}
                -> vStorage = {validated_data['storage_capacity']}
            - Create Virtual server 3
                -> VLAN: {validated_data['environment'].vlan}
                -> Primary Location: {validated_data['secondary_location']}
                -> vCPU = {validated_data['cpu_licenses']}
                -> vMEm = {validated_data['compute_units'] * 7}
                -> vStorage = {validated_data['storage_capacity']}
            - Create Virtual server 4
                -> VLAN: {validated_data['environment'].vlan}
                -> Primary Location: {validated_data['secondary_location']}
                -> vCPU = {validated_data['cpu_licenses']}
                -> vMEm = {validated_data['compute_units'] * 7}
                -> vStorage = {validated_data['storage_capacity']}
            - Create 1 x Database type {validated_data['level']}
                -> Name: {validated_data['database_name']}
                -> Character set: {validated_data['character_set']}
                -> National Character set: {validated_data['national_character_set']}
                -> Use RAC: {validated_data['use_rac']}
                -> Location: {validated_data['primary_location']}
                -> Type: {validated_data['level']}
                -> License: {validated_data['licence']}
                -> DNS information: {validated_data['dns'].server} - {validated_data['dns'].domain}
            - CSC request to enable monitoring
            - CSC request to enable backup with retention {validated_data['backup'].retention}
            - Feedback
                -> Database Names (SID)
                -> Database ports
                -> IP addresses: SCAN address
                -> 1 x User/password
            """
        else:
            description = 'Could not create ci'

        response = {
            'description': textwrap.dedent(description),
            'created_vms': [vm_1, vm_2, vm_3, vm_4],
            'created_dbs': [db_1, db_2, db_3, db_4, db_5, db_6],
            'created_clusters': [cl_1, cl_2],
        }

        return response

    def get_description(self, validated_data):
        level = validated_data['level']

        if level == 'Standalone':
            return self.standalone(validated_data)
        elif level == 'Cluster (DR)':
            return self.cluster_dr(validated_data)
        elif level == 'Geocluster (HA + DR)':
            return self.geocluster_ha_dr(validated_data)
        else:
            return 'No description available'
```

---

#### Review

What **I'm looking** for in this review is to make this code a bit more abstract as it became a bit messy. It looks like if I were to add more options this would become hardly maintainable in the future.

What I'm **not looking** for in a review:

- docstrings (I'll put those after I'll have the final version done)
- tests

Any other improvements / ideas / constructive critiques are welcome.

Comment: What is `UsdDBActions().reserve_ci(num)` doing? Returning a tuple of strings?

Comment: @six8 it's returning a list of strings, indeed (where `num` is `len(list)`). So, for example, `UsdDBActions().reserve_ci(2)` returns a list which looks like this: `['a', 'b']` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There's a lot of duplication here for like items. A sign that loops and templates will
  reduce redundancy.
- There's a few distinct steps here. Better to separate each step to separate concerns. For example, there's 1. creating the payload 2. creating the CI, 3. describing what was created.
- It looks like you can re-use `UsdDBActions`. If so, it would be better to make one instance
  of `UsdDBActions` and re-use it within the function.
- If you have control over `UsdDBActions.create_ci` it would be better to have it raise
  an exception on error instead of returning `False`. I'm assuming you can't change it
  so I did not.
- Avoid temp variables like `response` if you're just going to immediately return it.
- Location should be in the DB payload, not coming from the validated_data. Otherwise
  you're likely not creating the DB with the correct location.
- All of the description information should come from the payload, not `validated_data` as
  there are slight differences.
- There are slight differences in output format between the different methods. I'm assuming
  this is unintentional and I've ignored them.
- Presumably, one CI could be created while others fail. So rather than checking that
  all were created, it might be useful to output the ones that were created and the
  ones that failed individually.
- I wasn't sure how the number of IP addresses was derived for HA clusters so I omitted
  that information from the description.

Here's what I came up with:

```
from textwrap import dedent
from pprint import pprint


def group_number(i, total, groups):
    """
    For a zero based index item ``i`, of a list of ``total`` items,
    group into ``groups`` number of groups.

    For example, if there are 10 items and 3 groups, item 0 will
    be in group 0 and item 2 will be in group 0. Item 3 will be in
    group 1 and item 7 will be in group 2.
    """
    return (i // ceil(total / groups)) % groups


def make_payload(validated_data, vms, dbs, clusters=None):
    items = []

    locations = [
        validated_data['primary_location'],
        validated_data['secondary_location']
    ]

    if clusters:
        for i, cluster in enumerate(clusters):
            group = validated_data[
                'Active' if i >= len(clusters) / 2 else 'Standby']

            items.append({
                'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
                'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
                'class': 'Cluster',
                'status': 'To be installed',
                'ci': cluster,
                'hostname': f"{validated_data['database_name']} {group}",
            },)

    for i, (vm, db) in enumerate(zip(vms, dbs)):
        # 0 for first half, 1 for second
        half = group_number(i, len(vms), 2)

        # First half of VMs are in primary location
        location = locations[half]

        # First half of VMs are in first cluster
        cluster = None
        if clusters:
            cl = group_number(i, len(vms), len(clusters))
            cluster = clusters[cl]


        items.append({
            'level': validated_data['level'],
            'vlan': validated_data['environment'].vlan,
            'storage_capacity': validated_data['storage_capacity'],
            'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
            'hostname': vm,
            'number_of_cpu': validated_data['cpu_licenses'],
            'ram_gb': validated_data['compute_units'] * 7,
            'resolver_group': 'SSC.Computing & Internal Outsourcing',
            'twenty_four_team': '24H STAID Computing and Internal Outsourcing',
            'service_window': 'businesshours',
            'ci': vm,
            'status': 'To be installed',
            'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
            'class': 'Virtual Server',
            'location': location,
            'attached_to_server': cluster,
        })

        items.append({
            'level': validated_data['level'],
            'hostname': validated_data['database_name'],
            'attached_to_server': vm,
            'resolver_group': 'SSC.Database Oracle',
            'roleflagmanagement': 1,
            'service_window':  'businesshours',
            'model': 'Oracle 12.1.0.1',
            'ci': db,
            'status': 'To be installed',
            'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
            'class': 'Database',
            'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
            # Second half of DBs will be in secondary location
            'location': location,
            'license': validated_data['license'],
            'character_set': validated_data['character_set'],
            'national_character_set': validated_data['national_character_set'],
            'dns': validated_data['dns']
        })

    return items


def get_payload_description(payloads):
    vms = [p for p in payloads if p['class'] == 'Virtual Server']
    dbs = [p for p in payloads if p['class'] == 'Database']
    clusters = [p for p in payloads if p['class'] == 'Cluster']

    vm_s = 's' if len(vms) > 1 else ''
    db_s = 's' if len(dbs) > 1 else ''
    cluster_s = 's' if len(clusters) > 1 else ''

    description = dedent(f"""\
        Created VM{vm_s}: {', '.join(i['ci'] for i in vms)}
        Created DB{db_s}: {', '.join(i['ci'] for i in dbs)}
    """)

    if clusters:
        description += f"Created Cluster{cluster_s}: {', '.join(i['ci'] for i in clusters)}"

    description += dedent(f"""\

        - Portal information
        - Create network assets and log IP information in CMDB.
            -> {len(vms)} x IP address in VLAN {validated_data['environment'].vlan}
    """)

    for i, vm in enumerate(vms):
        num = i + 1
        if len(vms) == 1:
            title = f"1 x OVM type {vm['level']}"
        else:
            title = f"Virtual server {num}"

        description += dedent(f"""\
            - Create {title}
                -> VLAN: {vm['vlan']}
                -> Primary Location: {vm['location']}
                -> vCPU = {vm['number_of_cpu']}
                -> vMEm = {vm['ram_gb']}
                -> vStorage = {vm['storage_capacity']}
                -> Attached = {vm['attached_to_server']}
        """)

    for db in dbs:
        description += dedent(f"""\
            - Create 1 x Database type {db['level']}
                -> Name: {db['hostname']}
                -> Character set: {db['character_set']}
                -> National Character set: {db['national_character_set']}
                -> Location: {db['location']}
                -> Type: {db['level']}
                -> License: {db['license']}
                -> DNS information: {db['dns'].server} - {db['dns'].domain}
                -> Attached = {db['attached_to_server']}
        """)

    x1 = '1 x ' if len(dbs) > 1 else ''

    description += dedent(f"""\
        - CSC request to enable monitoring
        - CSC request to enable backup with retention {validated_data['backup'].retention}
        - Feedback
            -> Database Name{db_s} (SID)
            -> Database port{db_s}
            -> IP addresses
            -> Host name{db_s}
            -> {x1}User/password
    """)
    return description


def create_cis(validated_data, num_vms_and_dbs=1, num_clusters=0):
    """
    Args:
        num_vms_and_dbs (int): How many VMs and DBs to create. For
            each VM, one Database will also be created.
    """
    actions = UsdDBActions()

    # If it's cheap to do `reserve_ci`, then it would be better to do
    # it for vm, db, cl separately. If it's expensive, it can be done
    # this way.
    names = actions.reserve_ci(num_vms_and_dbs * 2 + num_clusters)
    clusters = [names.pop(0) for _ in range(num_clusters)]
    vms = [names.pop(0) for _ in range(num_vms_and_dbs)]
    dbs = [names.pop(0) for _ in range(num_vms_and_dbs)]

    payloads = make_payload(validated_data, vms, dbs, clusters)

    cis = [
        actions.create_ci(payload['ci'], payload)
        for payload in payloads
    ]

    if all(cis):
        description = get_payload_description(payloads)
    else:
        description = 'Could not create ci'

    return {
        'description': description,
        'created_vms': vms,
        'created_dbs': dbs,
        'created_clusters': clusters,
    }


class OrderDescription:
    @staticmethod
    def standalone(validated_data):
        return create_cis(validated_data, num_vms_and_dbs=1)

    @staticmethod
    def cluster_dr(validated_data):
        return create_cis(validated_data, num_vms_and_dbs=2)

    @staticmethod
    def geocluster_ha_dr(validated_data):
        return create_cis(validated_data, num_vms_and_dbs=4, num_clusters=3)

    def get_description(self, validated_data):
        level = validated_data['level']

        if level == 'Standalone':
            return self.standalone(validated_data)
        elif level == 'Cluster (DR)':
            return self.cluster_dr(validated_data)
        elif level == 'Geocluster (HA + DR)':
            return self.geocluster_ha_dr(validated_data)
        else:
            return 'No description available'


class UsdDBActions(object):
    """
    Stub for UsdDBActions
    """
    def reserve_ci(self, l):
        return [string.ascii_lowercase[i] for i in range(l)]

    def create_ci(self, name, payload):
        return True


class Mock(object):
    """
    Mock data that always returns an int value for missing key or
    attribute.
    """
    def __init__(self, defaults=None):
        self.defaults = defaults or {}
        self.counter = 0

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item not in self.defaults:
            self.counter += 1
            self.defaults[item] = self.counter
        return self.defaults[item]

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self[item]


validated_data = Mock({
    'environment': Mock(),
    'dns': Mock(),
    'backup': Mock(),
    'cpu_licenses': 1,
    'compute_units': 1,
    'database_name': 'db',
    'storage_capacity': 100,
    'level': 1,
    'license': 'foolicense',
})


pprint(OrderDescription.standalone(validated_data))
pprint(OrderDescription.cluster_dr(validated_data))
pprint(OrderDescription.geocluster_ha_dr(validated_data))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are some nice ideas over there. One question though: what if, in `create_cis` function, the number of vms is not equal to the number of dbs?

Comment: Then split `num_vms_and_dbs` into two parameters, one for VMs and one for DBs.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion:

- The payloads are pretty much the same, save for a couple of differences. I would create a function to construct these payloads:

  ```
  def vm_payload(validated_data, virtual_machine):
      return {
          'configuration': validated_data['environment'].configuration_cgkprimarykey,
          'hostname': virtual_machine,
          'number_of_cpu': validated_data['cpu_licenses'],
          'ram_gb': validated_data['compute_units'] * 7,
          'resolver_group': 'SSC.Computing & Internal Outsourcing',
          'twenty_four_team': '24H STAID Computing and Internal Outsourcing',
          'service_window': 'businesshours',
          'ci': virtual_machine,
          'status': 'To be installed',
          'organization': validated_data['environment'].organization_cgkprimarykey,
          'class': 'Virtual Server',
      }
  ```

  then, your invocation would be:

  ```
  created_vm_1 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(vm_1, vm_payload(validated_data, vm_1))
  created_vm_1 = UsdDBActions().create_ci(vm_2, vm_payload(validated_data, vm_2))
  ```

  This way, there will be only 1 copy of the VM payload, and 1 copy of the database payload
- The biggest issue: the three functions have so much in common. We should be able to consolidate the common code into a single function.
- Do not abbreviate. For example: db -> database
- In `standalone`, there is only 1 database variable, just name it `database` instead of `db_1`. Same for other variables such as `vm_1`.